# Android Resources$NotFoundException and InflateException: Binary XML file line #238:

Tags: android, android-resources

I am getting the following exceptions

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage/mypackage.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #238: Error inflating class <unknown>`

MyActivity setContentView

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.myxmlfile); // >>>>>>>> This is line 238
```

myxmlfile.xml

```
     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myanimation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/myanimationfile"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

`Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/myanimationfile.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020027`

This file does exist in the path res/drawable/

Following this I get

`Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/animation00013.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f02000a`

Again, animation00013.png does exist in the path

**I have extracted the apk using unzip and checked for these files. They exist.**

Comment: Try to restart your workspace and try it on.

Comment: Its a runtime exception on production. I wonder, since the unzip has these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried cleaning the project?  Sometimes the adt pluggin doesn't update the resources in R with new ids to appropriately account for file changes.  I have run into the issue before.